# Impact of a Salesforce Instance refresh or migration on Marketing Cloud Connect and Marketing Cloud org

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

A Salesforce instance change (refresh) will take place in production overnight from Saturday to Sunday. Salesforce will be "read-only" during the refresh period.

What are the impact of a Salesforce Instance refresh or migration on the Marketing Cloud Connect Integration?
What are the impacts regarding synchronization, Synchronized data extensions, Journeys, automations, any else on Marketing Cloud (SFMC) ?

Will the connexion between SFMC and CRM still work correctly after that ?
Do we need to make any changes or check anything that ?

thank you

Regards

Ludivine